# Joining a large table on two conditions without timing out

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to join two tables together and one table has two identifiers that I want.

```
select stations.id, stations.name, count (rentals.startstation_id) as station_starts, count (rentals.endstation_id) as station_ends
from ny.station as stations
Left Join ny.rental as rentals on stations.id = rentals.startstation_id
Left Join ny.rental as rentals on station.id = rentals.endstation_id
group by 1,2
```

However the ny.rental table is very large and when I run this query my SQL Workbench/J crashes. The stations table is rather small.

What is the optimal way to construct this query?

Comment: Why are you joining it twice and referencing it as the same name both times. This seems quite confusing. You may only need to join it a single time with an and or or

Comment: As @JoeLove above mentions, the problem is that you're joining the `ny.rental` twice. What you need to do is group the join conditions into one condition, with either `OR` or `AND` which ever is the correct one for your case.